# Implement complex, intersecting limitations on when and when not to log

Tags: javascript

It is a classic problem to handle ever changing requirements in a cleaner way without using too many nested if statements.
Here is my current code in JavaScript.

```
fetchApiData(url){
//log before start
  Logger.logFetchStartedEvent();
  try {
    data = backendApi.get(url);
    Logger.logFetchSucceededEvent();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.logFetchFailedEvent();
  }
}
```

Everything was going on a happy path. But I received a requirement that for some specific URLs we do not want to log at all.

No problem. I added a flag and switch and called it a day.

```
fetchApiData(url, shouldLog){
//log before start
  if(shouldLog) {
    Logger.logFetchStartedEvent();
  }
  try {
    data = backendApi.get(url);
    if(shouldLog) {
      Logger.logFetchSucceededEvent();
    }
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if(shouldLog) {
      Logger.logFetchFailedEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

And it didn't stop there.
New requirement drops in and asked to change to accommodate following requirements

- some url will log everything
- some url will log only error
- some url will log only if the API call url is an external site
- in some cases logging of fetchSucceeded event is needed, in some cases it is not needed.

I think you got the point.
I can add countless nested if/else conditionals and get it done but now I am sure there must be a better way for this type of issue. Now I feel like one method will become a whole if/else state machine god method.

This is what I came up with

```
fetchApiData(url,logOnStart, logOnSuccess, logOnFailure, logOnlyExternalLink){
  //log on start
  if(logOnStart) {
    if(logOnlyExternalLink) {
      if(isExternalLink(url)) {
        Logger.logFetchStartedEvent();
      }
    } else {
      Logger.logFetchStartedEvent();
    } 
  }
  try {
    data = backendApi.get(url);
    //log on success
    if(logOnSuccess) {
      // may need external url check again
      Logger.logFetchSucceededEvent();
    }
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if(logOnFailure) {
      if(errorType(error) === TimeOut)
      {
        Logger.logFetchFailedTimeOutEvent();
      } else if (errorType(error) === 404) {
        Logger.logFetchFailed404Event();
      } else {
        Logger.logFetchFailedEvent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did read a lot of questions about nested if/else problem but most of them end up with a foo/bar type examples and vague explanation which make no practical sense to me due to lack of experience.

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: I edited your question to better fit site standards.  You may want to make additional changes to better describe your code.  Note that your existing code makes no use of dependency injection or design patterns in general.  Nor is it object-oriented in itself.  If you posted more code, e.g. the `Logger` class, that might make it object-oriented.  Consider if you can post the entire code, as that is normally preferred.  People may want to recommend you move logic into the `Logger` class to simplify `fetchApiData`.

Comment: @TobySpeight  Your comment is using the old meta.codereview links rather than the newer codereview.meta links.  So [what your code is for](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and [state the task](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) will simply be broken in many browsers.  If that's a template that you copy and paste, you may want to edit it in the template.

Comment: Thanks @mdfst13 - I'll review and update my [SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When requirements are prone to change, passing a function as a parameter lets you offset the filtering logic to the caller.

```javascript
import fetch from 'node-fetch'                                                  
                                                                                
const log = (url,eventName) => console.log(`${url}: ${eventName}`)              
const makeLogger = shouldLog => url => eventName => {                           
    if (shouldLog(url,eventName)) log(url,eventName)                            
}                                                                               
                                                                                
const isExternalLink = url => !url.includes('localhost')                        
                                                                                
const neverLog = (url,eventName) => false                                       
const alwaysLog = (url,eventName) => true                                       
const logError = (url,eventName) => eventName === 'error'                       
const logExternalOrError = (url,eventName) =>                                   
    eventName === 'error' || isExternalLink(url)                                
                                                                                
const errorType = error => 'error'                                              
                                                                                
async function fetchApiData(url, shouldLog) {                                   
    const logger = makeLogger(shouldLog)(url)                                   
    logger('start')                                                             
    try {                                                                       
        const response = await fetch(url)                                       
        logger('success')                                                       
        return response                                                         
    }                                                                           
    catch (error) {                                                             
        logger(errorType(error))                                                
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               
                                                                                
async function main() {                                                         
    await fetchApiData('http://localhost:8080', neverLog) // no log             
    await fetchApiData('http://www.google.ca', alwaysLog) // full log           
    await fetchApiData('http://localhost:8080', logError) // log error only     
    await fetchApiData('http://localhost:8080', logExternalOrError)             
}                                                                               
                                                                                
main()
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, this is awesome. Looking at the comments on the question by moderators, I was actually waiting for it to get deleted. You saved my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Minimize function's role.

It is the `Logger` that should be filtering log events not `fetchApiData`.

However I suspect there is a design problem as I can not see how the logger knows the URL. EG `Logger.logFetchStartedEvent()` is not passed the URL

What needs to be done is for the logger to know what URL it is logging and that it filters log events according to what ever rules are current. That way your first snippet will is the correct code, and it also means any other code that is logging events can do so without needing to track a logging rule set.